# Why doesn't the INSERT key work in many applications?

Tags: windows

I've noticed that the INSERT key that toggles insert/overwrite mode doesn't seem to work in all the applications in a Windows 7 environment.

Overwrite functionality works in:

- Wordpad
- Eclipse
- My irc client
- Internet Explorer's input fields

Does not work in

- Notepad
- Google Chrome's input fields

Why is there a difference? Do applications deliberately force this behaviour one way or another?

Also, if I copy "xyz" to clipboard, type out "abc" and then go into overwrite mode and go to the first place, shouldn't that overwrite "abc" with "xyz" when I paste it? It just pastes the "xyz" in front of the "abc" even in overwrite mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwrite mode is handled specifically by applications and not by the windows standard forms, a word processor like word has of course reason to support it, also the most advanced editors , notepad is not in this category.

So what you say is actually the answer : "applications deliberately force this behavior one way or another" , and they do it in the code the developer choose to use.